# Save data in python

Tags: python, csv

I'm a little stuck here. I'm running a twitter api request loop and I need to store these tweets in a csv file. I'm doing something like:

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=search+ lang="en").items(num_tweets):
    data = tweet.text
    print (tweet.text)
```

My question is what's the easiest way to save tweets in this format:

```
["Hello world. I love Reddit!", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amaet."]
```

Comment: You can store them on a text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean saving the tweets list to csv?

Alternative way using pandas:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame(data={'tweets':tweet_list})
df.to_csv('./tweets.csv',index=False)
```

See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html for more.

Answer (score 0):

if `tweet.text` itself is a list then:

```
result = []
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=search+lang="en").items(num_tweets):
    result += tweet.text
```

if `tweet.text` is a string then use `result.append(tweet.text)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the csv library:

```
import csv
f = open("output.csv", 'w')
csvWriter = csv.writer(f)
# generate list of tweets here, or put this line in the for loop you already have
csvWriter.writerow(tweet.text)
```

You'll get an output csv file (comma separated value, use an application like excel to open it).

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to achieve what you want.

```
import csv

with open('filename', 'w') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=search+ lang="en").items(num_tweets):
        data = tweet.text
        wr.writerow(tweet.text)
```

You can check what [csv.QUOTE_ALL](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_ALL) does.

Comment: csv.QUOTE_ALL add parentheses for each letter!

Comment: @YoussefS. it should have added quotation marks for each string. see some example on web. i am not sure why it is happening in your case!